# nginx: Trying to curl from the Server itself via Domain Name results in Timeout

Tags: nginx, curl, server, opensuse

So I'm hosting a website sub.domain.com on my OpenSUSE Tumbleweed server via nginx as vhost. Access from the internet is working fine, but when I SSH into the server and try to `curl https://sub.domain.com` it results in a timeout. Is this expected behavior? If so, then is there a way to configure nginx to serve to itself as well via URL?

It's not a firewall issue, and I can `curl google.com` just fine.

Thanks for any ideas :) happy to post config files as well if required, but I've tried commenting out all but a very barebone config and it still didn't work.

- SSH into the server that is hosting sub.domain.com
- `curl https://sub.domain.com`
- Expectation: successful curl result
- Result: curl timeout

---

Troubleshooting as suggested by Zac Anger:

`dig sub.domain.com +short` => correct IP

`curl -v  https://sub.domain.com` =>

```
*   Trying 11.22.33.123:443...
* connect to 11.22.33.123 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to sub.domain.com port 443 after 130849 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

`curl -v 11.22.33.123 -H 'Host: sub.domain.com'` =>

```
*   Trying 11.22.33.123:80...
* connect to 11.22.33.123 port 80 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 11.22.33.123 port 80 after 129671 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 11.22.33.123 port 80 after 129671 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

`curl localhost -H 'Host: sub.domain.com'` =>

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

`curl https://localhost -H 'Host: sub.domain.com'` =>

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: Some troubleshooting steps: does `dig sub.domain.com +short` show the right IP, from inside the server? Any recent DNS changes? If you curl with the `-v` flag to show what's happening, does it time out on resolution or somewhere else? Do you have https correctly set up, and where is that terminating? If you curl localhost or your server's IP, but with `-H 'Host: sub.domain.com'`, does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! DNS is resolving correctly, curl fails after ´Trying 11.22.33.123:443´. Your last suggestion gives different results depending on what exactly I put in.. I'll post the outputs in the original question.

Comment: Okay, you can `-L` to follow the redirect if you need to, but I'm assuming that just redirects http to https so probably not relevant. The `-k` flag should get around the error in the last version. If that still doesn't work, then it might be worth trying telnet (`telnet sub.domain.com 443`, should tell you that you're connected and `Escape character is '^]'.` — if you can hit it in your browser, that _should_ be successful, but if it's not, it might mean you need to check out your ufw or iptables (and I'm not any good with either of those)

Comment: Thanks again :)
Yep, it's just a https redirect. -k does get rid of the TLS error, but it has no effect when trying to curl the domain. Telnet does work for localhost 443, but sub.domain.com 443 or 11.22.33.123 443 times out as well..

I'm running firewalld, but I have already tried disabling it completely for troubleshooting, no effect :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to fix it by adding the domain name to `/etc/hosts`:

It now has the following entry for 127.0.0.1:

`127.0.0.1 sub.domain.com localhost.localdomain localhost`

Thanks again to Zac Anger for helping me pin down the issue, much appreciated!

Comment: thanks, your solution fixed my issue but in my case I just add my private IP and sub.domian.com instead on localhost IP address